# Segmentation fault when printing numbers

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simple code that reads 20 numbers and then prints them in reverse order.

The code is the following.

```
int main(){
    int array[20];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    for (i=20; i > 0; i++) printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

I can't figure out why after I insert the numbers instead of printing them it gives me a segmentation fault (11)

Comment: `(i=20; i > 0; i++)` --> `(i=19; i > 0; i--)`

Comment: You should not have lost your (and ours) time asking that question. Just compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) to run the program step by step (and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)...). That would probably have been faster!

Comment: BTW you should test the return count (or failure) of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and take the habit of **reading the documentation** of every function that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the second `for`. You are trying to access the position n° 20 of the array but it contains only the indexes from
0 to 19, so your code should be:

`for (i=19; i >= 0; i--) printf("%d\n", array[i]);`

Answer (score 6):

You have 3 problems with the second `for`-loop:

1. it starts at 20 (which would get the 21th element)
2. you want to decrement i instead of increment
3. I believe you also want to display the first element at position 0 (so `>=0` instead of `>0`)

`for (i = 19; i >= 0; i--) printf("%d\n", array[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

In your loop

```
for (i=20; i > 0; i++) printf("%d\n", array[i]);
```

you have three faults. a) should start at `19`  and b) finish at `0` and c) should decrement, so

```
for (i=19; i >= 0; i--) printf("%d\n", array[i]);
```

Comment: @WeatherVane being a beginner sucks.

Comment: @linamamm no it doesn't. Just imagine what it would be like to know everything and then find it's all invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Change the second for loop to be 19 to 0 inclusive.

Comment: and also change ++ to --.

Comment: @GerardoZinno I believe *19 __to__ 0* covers that. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=20; i > 0; i++) printf("%d\n", array[i]);
```

This should be `i--`.